# Calculate new point coordinates after imageview translation

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, scale, android-canvas

I need help calculating new coordinates after an imageview translation.

I am working on an android app that will plot points on a map.

The map is downloaded from a backed service.

The points I need to plot come from the backend, and their positions are relative to the map size (8000w x 4450h).

The app (using glide) sets the image in a custom imageview. When that happens, the map is scaled down to fit the screen.

viewH = 735.

viewW = 1080.

I then need to plot the locations; however, the plotted coordinates need to be translated to match the new scale.

Here is how I am calculating it now...which gets the points in the correct area...but they are not precise (plotting to low on y axis):

newX = oldX / (originalMapHeight / imageviewHeight).

newY = oldY / (originalMapWidth / imageviewWidth).

Can someone help me get a more accurate translation of the x,y coordinates? I cannot find anything regarding this, but it may be due to me not knowing what exactly to search.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use min-max normalization for this. The formula is
[image]

For your case, the formula reduces to

NewX = (oldX * imageViewWidth) / originalMapWidth

NewY = (oldY * imageViewHeight) / originalMapHeight

Comment: Thank you for your response @Charan , but that gives me the same result

Your newX:
(oldX * imageViewWidth) / originalMapWidth = 494.7763

My newX:
oldX / (originalMapHeight / imageviewHeight) = 494.7763

Comment: Original Coords for Reference: (3665.0098,1183.9218)

Comment: Then you should check the coordinate system used in the image provided by the service and the coordinate system of the android views. For android views the (0,0) point is at the top-left corner I guess. If it is the same for the image generated by the service, then this transformation should work. Or else you have to make the necessary transformations to convert the image coordinate system to match with android view's coordinate system.